# Getting status code 404 in spring mvc application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a spring app in which i have controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/candidateHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView candidateHome() {
      return new ModelAndView("candidateHome", "command", new Candidate());
   }
```

a jsp name candidateHome

web.xml file

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
              <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
              <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>
          <context-param>
               <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
               <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
         </context-param>

   and servlet config file rest-servlet.xml

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ojp.controller" />
            <mvc:annotation-driven />

           <bean id="viewResolver"             class=  "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
          </bean>
```

.

when i am trying to access http://localhost:8080/RBTech/candidateHome, 
I am getting error 'HTTP Status 404 - /RBTech/WEB-INF/candidateHome.jsp'.

Can any one tell me what is wrong in this code. Thanks

Comment: I hope you are packaging it as a war. Can you unbundle and see if its there in corresponding location?

Comment: yes, candidateHome.jsp file is inside WEB-INF folder.